# How to get clients country code in my index.jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, localhost, country-codes

my landing page is index.jsp on localhost:8080.

this page is supposed to make a request to the database to retrieve products based on clients country in the scriptlet.

but since the jsp is server side, i have not been able to find the clients country.

i can use javascript to obtain the country code based on IP..but since jsp is executed before it , it is not possible to display the products based on country.

I am open to all suggestions to solve this dilemma.

Comment: grab the ip address from the client request and find country code of the ip on your jsp page.

Comment: is there a way to submit the index.jsp to itself?

Comment: yes, couple of ways are there, use same file name in action tag

Comment: can use please specify or show the basic code for that.

Comment: what  is your question to submit the page to itself or find country code from request?

Comment: i want to find the client country code in jsp

Comment: preffered language can be in HTTP headers. It not country itself, but sometimes can be used.